# Java - Why value of primitive wrapper class (e.g. Integer) isn't maintained in recursive calls?

Tags: java, recursion

I am using recursion and I want an `Integer` object to retain its value across recursive calls. e.g.

```
public void recursiveMethod(Integer counter) {
    if (counter == 10)
        return;
    else {
        counter++;
        recursiveMethod(counter);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer c = new Integer(5);
    new TestSort().recursiveMethod(c);
    System.out.println(c); // print 5
}
```

But in the below code (where I am using a `Counter` class instead of `Integer` wrapper class, the value is maintained

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Counter c = new Counter(5);
    new TestSort().recursiveMethod(c);
    System.out.println(c.getCount()); // print 10
}

public void recursiveMethod(Counter counter) {
    if (counter.getCount() == 10)
        return;
    else {
        counter.increaseByOne();
        recursiveMethod(counter);
    }
}

class Counter {

    int count = 0;

    public Counter(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.count;
    }

    public void increaseByOne() {
        count++;
    }
}
```

so why primitve wrapper class behaves differently. After all, both are objects and in the reucrsive call, I am passing the `Integer` object and not just `int` so that `Integer` object must also maintain its value.

Comment: You should simplify the code examples; the recursion is irrelevant...

Comment: @Oli the above code is just for the explanation of my doubt. So there is no point of irrelevancy... You should have understood this by yourself. I should say that your comment is irrelevant on this question.

Comment: The reason I said that is because when you are trying to make sense of some behaviour that you don't understand, it usually helps to reduce it to the simplest possible test-case (i.e. eliminate everything that's not relevant to the core problem).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Java wrapper types are *immutable*.  Their values never change.

`counter++` is really `counter = counter + 1`; i.e. a new object gets created.

Answer (score -1):

Some of the objects like String , Integer etc....are immutable even if they are objects....

try this link......

http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2003/04/immutable.htm

I recommend you do the following......

```
         public void recursiveMethod(Integer counter) 
         {
            if (counter == 10)
            return counter;  // return the value
            else 
            {
                    counter++;
                    counter=recursiveMethod(counter);
             }
         }

         public static void main(String[] args) 
         {
           Integer c = new Integer(5);
           c=(Integer)new TestSort().recursiveMethod(c);
           System.out.println(c); // print 5
          }
```

The only difference i believe u'll find on using both would be

using int is like using java primitives like any other language whereas Integer contains methods like `wait(), notify(),parsing,hashcode`  etc.....

Comment: @OliCharlesworth well my point is just to say java objects like Integer, String etc..are immutable....and i've just edited thee code and didn't considered taking into account it's compliation....